# Function fill unable to save value in database

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework, ebean

I am trying to fill a form with a predefined value using fill function

```
String loggedInUserEmail = session("email");
        Shop shop = new Shop();

        shop.email = Member.get(loggedInUserEmail);
        shopForm.fill(shop);    

        return ok(views.html.shop.create.render(shopForm, loggedInUserEmail));
```

where Shop and Member are models and Shop has a Member type email,get() confirm the email from database.
My create Shop form

```
@form(action = routes.ShopController.submit(), 'id -> "shopCreationForm", 'class -> "form-horizontal", 'role->"form") {

@inputText(userForm("name"), '_label -> "Shop Name",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("addressLine1"), '_label -> "Address Line 1",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("addressLine2"), '_label -> "Address Line 2",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("addressLine3"), '_label -> "Address Line 3",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("city"), '_label -> "City",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("town"), '_label -> "Town",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("phoneNumber"), '_label -> "Phone",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("email"), '_label -> "Owner Email" ,'_id -> "email",'class -> "form-control",'placeholder ->user )


    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create">
        <a href="@routes.ApplicationController.index" class="btn">Cancel</a>
    </div>


</fieldset>
        }
```

when i am submitting a form it routes to the same page means entering to the `if (filledForm.hasErrors())` condition and not saving any data to the database

Can anybody hep me ,i cant find what i am doing wrong.
stuck on it for many days
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to help yourself... ie. turn a debugger in your IDE, and try to find, where the problem rises (maybe some typo in field name or something? do you fill all fields required by model in your form ?

Comment: i have filled all the fields except the email,which i have already fixed i.e. `shopForm.fill(shop)`

Comment: And are you sure it's passed corrctly to the next action ? (is the field set corectly in the form?)

Comment: no i am not sure,now its giving NullPointerException on loading that page,i am really confused  now

Comment: trying to attach a debugger but it shows`Failed to connect to remote VM`

Comment: Can you print the errors (filledForm.errors) and see what fields are missing ?

Comment: @SKarthik i am doing this `if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
   
   
   String loggedInUserEmail = session("email");
   return badRequest(views.html.shop.create.render(filledForm,
     loggedInUserEmail));
  }` which loads the form with all the fields filled

Comment: do you have Id field in your case class? if so, add id field in form and hide that field

Comment: yes i have a id field in my entity added this to my form `<input type="hidden" class="form-control"   name="id" >` but still not storing  data to my email field

Comment: use println("Errors "+filledForm.errors) and see the console